# GeoJSON file splitting

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following code:

```
function addData() {
    var arrayData = [];
    if (response != null) {
        for (i = 0; i < response.results.features.length; i++) {
            arrayData.push(response.results.features[i]);
        }
    }
    return arrayData;
}

var arrayDataOP = addData();

function splitLines(arrayDataOP) {
    var arrayPOINTjson = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayDataOP.length; i++) {
        console.log(arrayData[i].geometry);
        if (arrayDataOP[i].geometry.type == "LineString") {
            for (key in arrayDataOP[i].geometry.coordinates.length) {
                arrayPOINTjson.push({
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "wheelchair": "yes",
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": arrayData[i].geometry.coordinates[key]
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(arrayPOINTjson);
    return arrayPOINTjson;
}
addData();
splitLines(arrayDataOP);
```

and it throws an error :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined`

and i dont know why couse if i `console.log(arrayData[i].geometry);` then i see a result.

But that's only one error

My point is that i want to split `LineString` inside my geoJSON file to points, like this:

```
{
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties":{
        "wheelchair":"yes",
    },
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":arrayData[i].geometry.coordinates[key]
    }
}
```

my geoSJON file sample:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "generator": "JOSM",
    "bbox": [
        23.4668,
        58.9198,
        23.6412,
        58.974
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "wheelchair": "yes",
                "smoothness": "intermediate",
                "highway": "footway"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [],
                    [
                        23.5410936,
                        58.9408252
                    ],
                    [
                        23.541092,
                        58.9408358
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5410706,
                        58.9410896
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5410448,
                        58.9412609
                    ],
                    [
                        23.541028,
                        58.9413309
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5409993,
                        58.9414512
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5408984,
                        58.9416477
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5408677,
                        58.9416962
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5407571,
                        58.9418706
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5405886,
                        58.9421204
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5405302,
                        58.9422071
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5403894,
                        58.9423888
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5401636,
                        58.9426413
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5400953,
                        58.9426593
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5399336,
                        58.9428447
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5399287,
                        58.9428504
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5399434,
                        58.9428895
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5394702,
                        58.9434341
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5394296,
                        58.943468
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5389324,
                        58.9439879
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5384256,
                        58.9445103
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5381597,
                        58.9447992
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5377425,
                        58.9452314
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5375449,
                        58.9454551
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "wheelchair": "yes",
                "highway": "footway"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        23.5408677,
                        58.9416962
                    ],
                    [
                        23.541045,
                        58.9417267
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5412157,
                        58.9417564
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want that my code final output is array of geoJSON object where
all `LineString` are splitted to `point`.

Comment: error is couse "=" sign is on the wrong place. i correct it

Comment: You've also forgotten to declare `i` using `var i` in your first for loop

Comment: tnx but do you know how do output that all ?

Comment: seems like you should change `(key in arrayDataOP[i].geometry.coordinates.length)` to `(key in arrayDataOP[i].geometry.coordinates)`

Comment: TNX for that information!